# Unit Testing CoroutineExceptionHandler

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

Hello I have this code that uses coroutines and I want to unit test it :

My problem is that my exception is never catched by the `CoroutineExceptionHandler`.

My code looks something like the following :

```
 fun request() {
    val handler = CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable -> liveData.value = Resource.error(throwable.message) }

    viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
        liveData.value = Resource.loading()
        val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { useCase.request() }
        liveFdDetails.value = Resource.success(result)
    }
}
```

And my test :

```
fun testError() = runBlocking {

    //Given
    val observer: Observer<Resource<Data>> = mock()
    whenever(useCase.request()).thenThrow(Error("MSG"))
    viewModel.liveData.observeForever(observer)

    //When
    viewModel.request()

    //Then
    inOrder(observer).apply {
        verify(observer).onChanged(Resource.loading())
        verify(observer).onChanged(Resource.error("MSG"))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
viewModelScope.launch(handler) {
```

Here you launch a coroutine in a scope other than that of `runBlocking`. Since it's not its child coroutine, `runBlocking` won't wait for it to complete. Most probably the whole test completes before the coroutine has had the time to start in an IO thread and fail.

However, given what code you have in the exception handler I think you aren't using the right tool.

Coroutine exception handlers are not a mechanism for your regular exception handling, they are just a last-resort measure to have a chance to observe an exception that your code should have handled, but didn't due to a bug.

For business logic-level error handling, use the natural mechanism which is `try-catch`. If you have a lot of repeated logic for error handling, you can always write an `inline fun(block: inline () -> Unit)` that wraps the block in such a boilerplate try-catch.

Comment: How to use handler when you want to specify Dispatcher in the `launch`?  `viewModelScope.launch(exceptionHandler) {withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {...}}` ?

Comment: `launch(handler + IO)`